# E-reader angularJs with cordova and ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working with cordova, ionic and agularjs.
I would like to implement kind of e-reader.
The user insert a long html text and my app should show that text as a ebook into a e-reader swiping left and right.
My problem is especially how to fin the right amount of text to display due every device has a different height.

Do you know if there is a library that could help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use example here: [angularjs text area character counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20603107/angularjs-text-area-character-counter) to caluclate nummber of chars that you can get on one page, and then just use nummberOfChars/charsPerPage and you would get number of pages that you need.