# How to create a character counter for textarea ? (angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, textarea, mean-stack

**CODE:**

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="content">Content</label>
      <textarea name="content" data-ng-model="vm.article.content" id="content" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="1400 characters long at least" required ng-minlength="1400" ng-maxlength="14000" highlight-on-error></textarea>
        <!--counter-->
      <br>
      <span class="form-help">{{1400-vm.article.content.length}}         
       Characters</span>
      <div ng-messages="vm.form.articleForms.content.$error" role="alert">
        <p class="help-block error-text" ng-message="required">Article title is required.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

---

**SITUATION:**

I am trying to display an error message on submit if word count is too low with ng-messages: the error message does not appear.

I am also trying to update in real-time a word count of the text area. It doesn't udate.

What have I done wrong ?

---

**REFERENCE:**

[angularjs text area character counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20603107/angularjs-text-area-character-counter)

---

**P.S.:**

I am using mean.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working fine :

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.12/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app> 
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="content">Content</label>
      <textarea name="content" data-ng-model="vm.article.content" id="content" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="1400 characters long at least" required ng-maxlength="1400" highlight-on-error></textarea>
        <!--counter-->
      <br>
      <span class="form-help">{{1400-vm.article.content.length}}         
       Characters</span>
      <div ng-messages="vm.form.articleForms.content.$error" role="alert">
        <p class="help-block error-text" ng-message="required">Article title is required.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
```

Comment: But I need ng-minlength.

Comment: @Coder1000 You should add validation like min allow 1400 character

Comment: Where ? Could you please explain ?

Comment: @Coder1000 check it  - https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation-with-ngmessages

Comment: This does not help in this case:  the ng-message "required" doesn't show up for example in my code :/

Comment: Please edit your answer with a way to prevent submit unless >1400 characters.

Comment: @Coder1000 sure

Comment: Hello, could you please edit your question as you said you would :D ?

Comment: I will @Coder1000

Comment: It's fine actually, I moved validation to the server :D