# Ionic text-area input event

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I am using Ionic3, and have:

```
        <ion-textarea (change)="reviewChange()"></ion-textarea>
```

When a user changes the input, and blurs focus from the text area, the `reviewChange()` function is triggered as expected.

**Question**

Is it possible to add an equivalent of the `ion-searchbar`'s `ionInput` event? i.e. when a user types text, an event is triggered for each key pressed.

**Background**

I am trying to track how many characters a user has left. e.g.

```
500 characters left
```

In order to do so, I need to track each key stroke. Unless there's a better way, or some automated way to do this?

Comment: You can use ngModel value length..

Comment: The answer is here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20603107/angularjs-text-area-character-counter

Comment: Thanks, just saw that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An easier way would be to bind the text area to a property from the component

```
<ion-textarea maxlength="500" [(ngModel)]="myText"></ion-textarea>
```

And below that text area you can show the characters left like this

```
<span>{{ 500 - myText.length }} characters left</span>
```

Comment: maxlength attribute dosen't restrict the number of characters to given value, i.e. 500. @sebaferreras

Comment: It should @KhushbooMulani. Could you please create a **[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/)** with your code?

Comment: It restricts when I submit my form (It actually submits just 500 chars removing the rest of the chars) but it does not block the user from typing in the texarea even when max limit reaches.

Comment: It should not work like that... Please create a demo so I can take a look to see what could be happening @KhushbooMulani

Answer (score 3):

You may simply try the (input) event. It fires for every key input.

```
     <ion-textarea [(ngModel)]="text" (input)="reviewChange()"></ion-textarea>
```